# How to increment value in the object Date each time by click event using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I wanna change the date object every time when I'm clicking the button. I'm trying to handle it using the following function:

```
.on('click', '.change-date-button', function () {
    Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
        var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        return date;
    }
    var date = new Date();
    console.log(date.addDays(3));
}
```

But as result, I get the same object. How to increment and decrement the date object in the correct way and get a new date added seven days every time by click?
As an example, I get 18/07/2022 several times, however, I need to get 21/07/2022, 24/07/22, etc... by the next click.

Comment: Of course you always get the same result, if your _starting_ value is always the same: `var date = new Date();`. You either need to initialize this outside of the click handler, or keep track of how many times you clicked, so that you can add 3 times number of clicks.

Comment: "the date object"... which object are you referring to? `date`? But then why do you assign `new Date()` to it at *every* click?

Comment: And the adding of the `addDays` method to the Date object, should not be inside the handler function to begin with.

Comment: it's already resolved by moving the variable outside the function. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to redefine a method on a prototype at *each* click of a button. You might as well just do the job *inline* -- without any function.

Also, your function explicitly does the job of *not* changing the date, but returning a new one, and the function is always called with *today's* date and time -- at every click.

You refer to "the date object" as a global object, but then you need to create it as a global:

```js
var date = new Date(); // <-- outside handler scope
// ...

$(document).on('click', '.change-date-button', function () {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3);
    console.log(date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="change-date-button">Add three days</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the date-fns library, because in this case you wouldn't need to redo something that already exists in a simplified way.

https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/add

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).